# Amount of free energy in the Earth-ionosphere waveguide

Tags: thermodynamics, electromagnetism

How much free energy is there in the Earth-ionosphere waveguide resulting from the constant bombardment of lightning strikes all over the Earth, and how do you go about calculating an estimate for it?

Comment: Vote to close, to discourage those "free energy" fools asap.

Comment: Problem, officer?

Comment: F*E* is a very bad keyword, so I wiped it from the question. Now I think it is ok.

Comment: I don't think so. Go start your own question Gestapo.

Comment: There's no indication that the phrase "free energy" is being used here in its problematic perpetual-motion-machine sense, but the phrase is confusing and misleading in this context. Are you really talking about free energy in the thermodynamic sense (e.g., Helmholtz or Gibbs free energy)? If so, I don't see why: it seems to me that what you mean is quite simply "energy," not free energy. Your question will be much clearer, and you're much more likely to get good responses, if you phrase it that way.

Comment: Oh, and a bit of general advice: if people are mistakenly convinced that you're behaving irrationally, calling them "Gestapo" is very unlikely to convince them or anyone else otherwise. You might want to rethink your rhetorical tactics.

Comment: Free energy in the thermodynamic sense, energy that is available for work by the thermodynamic system, Herr Bunn.

Comment: No need to start whining about rhetorics, after a moderator has been caught with his pants down.

Comment: Still no indication Herr Bunn :=) ?

Answer (score 1):

http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Lightning#Harvesting_lightning_energy

As a rough estimation, you can take energy of 1 lightening 5 MJ. Multiply that by number of strikes per day/year and you are done.

Comment: But the question is how much of that ends up in the waveguide as ELF radiation?